# Data representation of partition of a rectangle?

Tags: data-structures

I have a rectangle. I want to split it into a number of nonoverlapping smaller rectangles. Any good data structure to represent the partition?

Comment: B-tree or quad-tree might be the way to go. What is it going to be used for?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question. "Good" depends on the exact nature of the partition and on the operations you need to do on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this could be interesting, how about:
[image]

```js
var w = $('#rect').width();
var h = $('#rect').height();
var ratio = h/w;

var splitAcross = 10;//Ten divisions squared *Changeable*
var splitW = w/splitAcross;
var splitH = ratio*splitW;//Split across and down

var divRects = document.createElement("div");  // Create with DOM
divRects.style.width = splitW+'px';
divRects.style.height = splitH+'px';

var span = 0;
var spl = 0;
while (span < splitAcross)
{
  spl++;

  var cln = divRects.cloneNode(true);

  if (splitW*spl % w == 0) span++;

  $("#rect").append(cln);

}
//Removeable*** this is just to show divisions
$("#rect div").each(function (){
  $(this).animate({
    left: ($(this).offset().left-(w/2))*0.1,
    top: ($(this).offset().top-(h/2))*0.1
  }, 1000).animate({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }, 1000);
});
//Removeable
```

```css
#rect div {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: -1px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background:#5fba7d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect" style="width:450px; height:200px"></div>
                  <!--width:450px; height:200px *Changeable*-->
```